# What does the term "Queens English" Mean?

Tags: grammar, british-english

I am reading a book and I stumbled apon the expression "Queen's English".

My question is:

```
What does it mean.
```

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Please provide the source or the line or para from where you have read it.

Comment: [OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=queen%27s+english&ls=a) is a great place to start looking. Feel free to ask a follow-up question here if you are still confused, but be sure to include your research in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it's proper (upper-class) British English, as would be spoken by the Queen (of England).

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Queen%27s-English) says:

> Standard English language as written and spoken by educated people in Britain.

Comment: Some more info: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/education/schools/god-save-the-queens-english-our-language-is-under-threat-from-ignorance-inverted-snobbery-and-deliberate-dumbing-down-2099825.html and http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/10337912/Speak-the-Queens-English-if-you-want-to-sound-intelligent-and-be-trusted.html